# Music smiliar to Schiller

Tags: similar-artists

I wonder if there's any other artists, bands or music projects similar to [Schiller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiller_%28band%29). Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list:

Ayla,
Sash!,
Blank & Jones,
Chicane,
Lighthouse Family,
Fragma,
Delerium,
4 strings,
Robert Miles,
Thomas Gold.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Bundle of thanks steelerfan! looks like I hit the jackpot, the first one you've mentioned "Ayla" is exactly what I wanted. Listened Robert Miles thought but haven't checked out the others yet. Thanks again..

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Kebu sounds very similar to Schiller to me.

https://www.discogs.com/artist/995936-Kebu